# Need help saving the answer from a Select into Database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there;

I need some help; I need to save the answer from a select into my database. I do not know where I went wrong. Here is some details regarding my code.

1. I have a database named 'lib'
2. The table is named 'games'
3. I need to save the following into the table; 1) Game (all the words) and 2) Type
4. It is for a tournament website. So that I can make it available on the LAN via XAMPP.

Here is my code.
http://pastebin.com/iP7MCMzJ

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the help! I have found and fixed my problem! In my database the VARCHAR was limited to 50 characters. I have fixed that. **Now all is good :)**

Thanks once again!

Comment: The code just shows how you output the dropdown.  Where is your code for trying to handle the POSTed data and insert into the database?

Comment: Here is my code. http://pastebin.com/iP7MCMzJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not showing any code but this is how I'd expect it to work based on your description:

Your HTML will want to look something like:

```
<?php echo '<option name="game" value="' . htmlentities($game) . '">' . $row['game'] . '</option>'; ?>
```

Notice the `name` attribute? Also, I changed the way the HTML was written as yours was very tough to read.

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['game']) && isset($_POST['type'])){
$game = $_POST['game'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

// PLEASE CLEAN YOUR INPUT PRIOR TO INSERTING THIS DATA!

Insert into games (Game, Type) VALUES ($game, $type)
}
else{
echo( "error getting info");
}
```